# On button click delete a row after delete will add a new row on the same spot jquery

Tags: jquery, uitableview

In layman's term i want to replace a certain row on button click.

i tried

```
$(document).on('click', '#removerow', function() {
    var addedRows = [];
    $("#tableid").find("tr").remove();
    var $row = $("<tr class=''><td class='tdlabel'> <span>New Row </td></tr>");
    addedRows.push($row);
    $("table#tableid tr").last().before($row);
});
```

It just remove the rows in the table but did not add the rows that added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use convenient in this case [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method:

```
var addedRows = [];

$(document).on('click', '.removerow', function() {

    var $row = $("<tr class=''><td class='tdlabel'> <span>New Row </td></tr>");
    addedRows.push($row);

    $(this).replaceWith($row);
});
```

Also if you want to collect array of added rows you need to declare `addedRows` array outside of event handler, otherwise you recreate it on each click.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. Use html method you don't need resubscribe event anymore.

```js
$('table tr').click(function() {
  $(this).html('<td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>' + new Date() + '</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this help.